# Ajax PHP : cant go to new php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The goal for my script is showing list of results from page1.php to page-listes.php

I incluse all method to my ajax call the sucess method was fired but page list not displayed

The ajax call code is :

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
 url: "page-listes.php", 
 data: "name="+name+"&type="+type+"&region="+region+"&aliment="+aliment+"&periode="+periode,
dataType: 'html'
}) .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
    })
    fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
});
```

And the php result file is :

```
    <?php
        try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8;host=localhost;dbname=reps-bd', 'tchiko', 'tchiko');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $region = $_POST['region'];
        $aliment = $_POST['aliment'];
        $periode = $_POST['periode'];

        // recuperer la liste 
        $repListe = $bdd->query('SELECT re.libelle libeller, t.libelle libellet, r.nom nom, r.nb_personne nb, r.image image, r.date date        
    FROM course r 
    INNER JOIN region re ON r.id_region=re.id_pays   
    INNER JOIN type t ON t.id_type=t.id_type
    WHERE r.nom LIKE "%'.$name.'%"')
        or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    ?>
// some html code
<?php 
                while ($cours= $repListe->fetch()){
                $fch_image = 'images/temp/'.$cours['image'].'.jpg';    
            ?>

            <div class="offer_list clearfix">

                <div class="offer_item clearfix">
                    <div class="offer_image"><a href="offers-details.html"><img src="<?php echo $fch_image;?>" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="offer_aside">
                        <h2><a href="offers-details.html"><?php echo strtoupper($cours['nom']);?></a></h2>
                        <div class="offer_descr">
                            <p>...............</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="offer_data">
                            <div class="offer_price"><?php echo $cours['diff'];?></div>
                            <span class="offer_miliage"><?php echo $cours['libellet'];?></span>
                            <span class="offer_regist"><?php echo $cours['date'];?></span>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
<?php
}
$repListe->closeCursor();
}
?>
// some html code
```

I think the php file was correct,but nothing happen when i call it

Comment: can you try to use `success` instead of `done` and instead `fail` use `error`? just curios about it, cause never used `done`.... also you missed a `.` in front of `fail`

Comment: i'm using new version of jquery, the sucess was deprecated since 1.8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code doesn't have any mechanism to actually append the response to your page. For instance, if you had a `<p>` with an `id` of `myParagraph` and want to append the response there, then your `done` callback should look like this:

```
.done(function(response){
  $('#myParagraph').html(response);
});
```

Comment: i've add this codebut doesn't work also : $("div.body_wrap").html(response);

Comment: no error in console, i see the new code of new page in response but i've remove the scripts and css specifics for new page and title header doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Developer tools in your browser is your friend :-) Right click -> Inspect element (Chrome/Firefox), switch to console tab and you will see what is wrong. You forgot dot before fail() method :-)

Comment: i've dot before fail() in my source